# How to solve '.git/index.lock': No such file or directory' error?

Tags: windows, git

## Summary

I recently lost the ability to make any changes using Git on my Windows system. After a few days of not using my PC I come back to a non functional git so I have no idea what caused this issue.

## Examples:

**git add or git checkout** => fatal: Unable to create 'dummy-repo/.git/index.lock': No such file or directory

**git clone** =>  fatal: could not create work tree dir 'DummyRepo': No such file or directory

As a side note, this problem occured after trying to start my Flutter application, which could not retrieve the packages because of an OS error where access was denied. I'm thinking this is either because of some write permissions being messed up or a certain process locking a file.

## What I've tried so far:

- Closing all files and rebooting PC
- Uninstalling and reinstalling Git
- Run Git Bash as an administrator
- Changed system write permission to my user account for all files

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

On Windows, this may happen if you enabled the "Ransomware protection" in Setting > Windows security > Virus & threat protection.

You need to add an exclusion for git.exe, or move the project outside a protected folder.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it myself by changing the location of my project to C:\ instead of a way longer path. This was never a problem before but it works so I'm happy.

Answer (score 0):

I did 2 things:

1. I found that there was a file named 'index' in '.git/' directory. I made a copy of it, and renamed the copy as 'index.lock'.
2. Under 'Ransomware protection', I temporarily switched off 'Controlled folder access'.

Problem solved.

After I am done, I switched 'Controlled folder access' back on.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating that file in your .git directory, you can use these commands in Git Bash or linux/mac

```
cd .git
touch index.lock
```

On Windows CMD

```
cd .git
type nul > index.lock
```

Comment: result on Windows: The system cannot find the specified file.

Comment: You've created the file manually as I've instructed but the problem still exists?

Comment: Creating the file via cmd would give that error message saying the specified file for creation could not be found. I went ahead and created the index.lock file using the Windows GUI. Git add errors: error: unable to create temporary file: No such file or directory
error: FlutterApp/lib/src/widgets/AppDrawer.dart: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file 'FlutterApp/lib/src/widgets/AppDrawer.dart'
fatal: updating files failed
Unlink of file 'C:/Users/11600864/Documents/3TIN Stage/Yunify Projects/MyClient_Flutter/.git/index.lock' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)

Comment: For the record, you should never manually create this file unless you know what you're doing. It's used internally by Git as a lock file, and its presence prevents all index updates.